# Funcion or en laravel blade para preguntar si existe (isset en php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

le estoy preguntando al programa que si existe la variable $director que me la imprima con sintaxis laravel, sino que me muestre 'No hay ningún director', pero me sale error(la variable $director no esta definida). El mismo problema con sintaxis php si funciona. adjunto código de ambos.

php:
consulta ternaria...

```
<?= isset($director) ? $director : "No hay ningún director"?>
```

Laravel Blade

```
{{ $director or 'No hay ningún director' }}
```

Gracias

Comment: Entonces hay que checkar la carga de la variable como menciona @BetaM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba de esta forma:

```
@if(isset($director))
    {{ $director}}
@else
    No hay ningún director
@endif
```

Comment: muchas gracias. Si funciono.